# Prove that any two $m$-simplexes are homeomorphic via an affine map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove that any two $m$-simplexes are homeomorphic via an affine map.

Let $A = \{a_0, ..., a_m\} \text{ and } B= \{b_0, ..., b_m\}$ be convex spans of their respective sets of points.

I've proven that if we define: $T : [a_0, ..., a_m] \rightarrow [b_0, ..., b_n]$ as the restriction of the affine map $\text{affine span(A)} \rightarrow R^k$ by: $$T(\sum t_i a_i) = \sum t_i T(a_i) = \sum t_i b_i$$ then $T$ is continuous, and bijective.

But I'm struggling with proving that $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

I see that I would have to show that $U \in T_A \Rightarrow T(U) \in T_B$.  I know that $U \in T_A \Rightarrow U = [a_0, ..., a_m] \cap O$ such that $O \in T_{\text{affine span(A)}}$ , but I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: You could also define $S \colon [b_0,\dots,b_m] \to R^k$ in a similar way. Then prove that the image of $T$ is (contained in ) $[b_0,\dots,b_m]$ and similarly for $S$. Finally, prove that they are each others inverse.

Comment: How does that prove that they're homeomorphic?  Wouldn't that just show a bijective relationship?

Comment: Hint: compact and Hausdorff

Comment: You've already proven that $T$ is continuous. $S$ is defined in a completely similar way, so is also continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly straightforward result that gets buried in notation.

If we can show that $A = \operatorname{co} \{a_0,...,a_m\}$ is homeomorphic to the simplex $\Sigma = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1} | \sum_{k=0}^m x_k = 1, x_k \ge 0 \}$ (I am using non standard notation
$x=(x_0,...,x_m)$), then the result follows.

I am presuming that the $a_k$ are in some Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$.
Let $\overline{\mathbb{H}} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{H}$ and define
the notation $\overline{a} = \binom{1}{a} \subset \overline{\mathbb{H}}$, and $\pi:\overline{\mathbb{H}} \to \mathbb{H}$
by $\pi(\overline{a}) = a$.

Note that the set $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^m$ forms a simplex **iff** the collection $\{\overline{a}_k \}_{k=0}^m$ is linearly independent.

Define $\overline{T} : \mathbb{R}^{m+1} \to \overline{\mathbb{H}}$ by
$\overline{T} x = \sum_k x_k \overline{a_k}$, note that
$\overline{T}$ is continuous and $\overline{T} \Sigma = \{1\} \times 
A$. Note that if $\overline{T} x_1 = \overline{T} x_2$
then we must have $x_1 = x_2$ since the $\overline{a_k}$ are
linearly independent.

Note that $\overline{T}^* \overline{T} $ defines an invertible
$(m+1)\times (m+1)$ matrix.

The map $T=\pi \circ \overline{T}$ defines a continuous map
from $\Sigma$ to $A$, we need to show that there is a continuous
inverse.

Define the continuous map $S:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ by
$S a = (\overline{T}^* \overline{T})^{-1} \overline{T}^* \overline{a}$ and note that
if $\overline{T} x = \overline{a}$ then
$\overline{T}^* \overline{T} x= \overline{T}^* \overline{a}$
and hence $x=(\overline{T}^* \overline{T})^{-1} \overline{T}^* \overline{a} = Sa$. That is, $S \circ T$ is the identity.

Note that $Sa = (\overline{T}^* \overline{T})^{-1} \overline{T}^* \binom{1}{0} + (\overline{T}^* \overline{T})^{-1} \overline{T}^* \binom{0}{a}$ which is an affine map.